# How to convert USB web cam to an ethernet device to give it an IP

Tags: windows, usb

Is it possible to convert a USB web cam to ethernet or give it an IP address ? I know about USB-over-Cat5 adapter but that merely increases the length of the cable, I don't think it converts the signal.

I would like to know the software and hardware possibilities if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Hardware:** [Connect up to 2 x USB Webcams directly to the Internet or Your Lan](http://www.camsecure.co.uk/CamsecureUSBtoIP.html)
- **Software:** [Share Usb Web Cam](http://share-usb-web-cam.smartcode.com/)

Comment: Another hardware option would be a wireless USB hub http://www.iogear.com/product/GUWH104KIT/

Answer (score 1):

You can get [convertors on ebay](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/iCAMView-Plus-webcam-server-ip-server-/360247648338?pt=UK_Computing_ComputerComponents_Webcams&hash=item53e06ee052) that have a cat5 and one or two USB interfaces. When the USB webcam is plugged in you can connect to a Web page in the convertor and see the picture. They work pretty well (I have a couple) but only support a limited number of webcam/usb chipsets.

Answer (score 0):

See this DynDNS article : [DVRs, CCTVs and Cameras](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/dvrs.html).
DynDNS is the service that you will need to give a domain name on the Internet to the webcam.

See also this wiki: [How do I access my device from outside my home network?](http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/questions/16/how-do-i-access-my-device-from-outside-my-home-network)